# How can I get slashes and double quotes to be allowed in a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, html

I'm using a validation script called VDAEMON and in applying it to an element we have to set the type of characters we want allowed in a field with a regular expression.  Due to the fact that the purpose my element serves is for people to explain things I want them to be able to pretty much have full keyboard usage to express their ideas.

So far I came up with this to allow all the characters

```
regexp="/^[0-9a-z!@#$%^&*():;<>,.?\/\s]*$/i"
```

The only ones I can't get to work is the /\ and ".  Of course the " changes the html structure and the / and \ are used in the syntax, which I'm not too sure on which language that is I just kinda winged it with the other characters and tested it and it happened to work.

It did say it needed to be any perl compatible expression.  Does anybody know how to achieve this?

///////////////////////UPDATE///////////////////////////////

Here's a sample of the HTML I'm trying to call it in

```
<textarea id="my_comp" name="How_did_you_hear_about_my_Company" class="tex_inp01" style="width:88%; height:100px; font-size:14pt;"></textarea>
<vlvalidator name="My_Company" type="regexp" control="How_did_you_hear_about_my_Company" errmsg="Invalid Type Format" regexp="/^[0-9a-z!@#$%^&*():;<>\\,.?\/\s]*$/i">
```

Comment: Just checking here but, did you already try escaping them? ( \/ and \" respectfully.)

Comment: try `regexp='~^[0-9a-z!@#$%^&*():;<>,.?\/\s"]*$~i'`

Comment: Can you provide your PHP usage of that regex and the string you want to parse in it?

Comment: try this /^[0-9a-z!@#$%^&*():;<>\\",.?\/\s]*$/i

Comment: @Francis Stalin that worked, except the quotes didn't register properly, they changed the dynamics of the html, so it doesn't work with double and single quotes unfortunately.

Comment: can you pls give me  the sample..

Comment: try /^[0-9a-z!@#$%^&*():;\="'<>,.?\/\s]*$/i   i have used this as a sample -  <html>hello world <font class='height:20px;'>style here</html>

Comment: I added a sample to the original post

Comment: Why are you limiting the input of a text field at all? Just allow all input and properly escape it when displaying or using it elsewhere. Absolutely no need to restrict the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try single quotes.

```
preg_match('~^[0-9a-z!@#$%^&*():;<>,.?/\s"]*$~i', $str);
```